# How to do a dynamic href below?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net-mvc

How to do dynamic href below?

@Model.inbox_type is a dynamic value either "1", "2", "3" .. "6", how to apply it with href below?

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index/" + "@Model.inbox_type" , "Inbox")'">Exit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a parameter on `Url.Action` instead of string appending

```
<button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Inbox", new { id: @Model.inbox_type })'">Exit</button>
```

Note that `id` is the parameter you're expecting in the action function

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
```

You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-urlhelper-action(system-string-system-string-system-object)) for a reference

Comment: it's anonymous type warning!

Comment: if you define a param class for that and call it there, the warning will get away, but it's kind of troublesome for all these params passing down. By the way, does it work for you? @FBDon

Comment: By the way, I added [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#system-web-mvc-urlhelper-action(system-string-system-string-system-object)) in the answer, you can check it out :D @FBDon

Comment: I tried the following:

<button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Inbox", new { inbox_type = "@Model.inbox_type" })'">Exit</button>

but don't have idea to get the value of @Model.inbox_type

Comment: could you inspect your HTML and check what the URL is on that element? @FBDon

Comment: yours already works properly, it's just slight typo:

<button class="btn btn-block btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Inbox", new { id =@Model.inbox_type })'">Exit</button>